# Using one xml file to load different activities

Tags: android

I have an activity which displays a list of items in a listview,about 160 items. Now i need to show the entire message when i click on any item in the listview. What bugs me now is whether i have to create 160 xlm layouts to display each item in a seperate activity containing just a textview.

I'm hoping i could create only one xml file with a textview inside so that whenever i click on an item in the listview it will query the database and display the details of the item in the textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity fetches whatever layout you supply to it. It uses the layout that you define in `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` method of your activity.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout) //Just supply whatever layout you wish
    }
```

Create one layout and then in your activity change their `setContentView` like mentioned in the code.

Comment: okay. so does it mean that i can do an intent.putExtra in the onItemClick listener of the listview so that it passes the string value of the item i want to retrieve  from the database which i can then put a json string request in the onCreate method of my new Activity class when i do a getExtra

Comment: Sorry, I could not quite understand what exactly you mean, you could create a shared preference, save your data there or create a singleton data holder class, that way you can share the loaded data in your activity. Also, this question is off-topic(not related to the original question).

Comment: Wow thats even better .Thank you very much i will implement it now.